# OAuthException 191 Problem: Can't Load URL

Tags: facebook, api, oauth-2.0

I got stuck with the problem of facebook login with OAuthException 191 as shown in this picture which show redirect URI as "http://zsize.openservice.or.th/callback/facebook"
 ["OAuthException 191 - Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCazR.jpg)

I thought that something gone wrong with Valid OAUTH Redirect URI.  However, when I have checked Valid OAUTH Redirect URI section of my Facebook API as shown in picture below, it has been shown as "https://zsize.openservice.or.th/callback/facebook" validated by Redirect URI Validator.

[Valid OAUTH Redirect URIs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jn8IS.jpg)

This has really puzzled me because I though that I have already changed the OAUTH Redirect URI to "https://" but the link on the page that show "OAuthException 191" still show the Redirect URI as "http://".  How to deal with this kind of error? Please help me.

Oh, BTW, the code that related to the Facebook Login is here:

Authorize to Provider:

```
@app.route('/authorize/<provider>',methods=['GET','POST'])
 def oauth_authorize(provider):
    try:
        oauth = OAuthSignIn.get_provider(provider)
        except ValueError:
            return "Authorize Failure"
        return oauth.authorize()
@app.route('/callback/<provider>',methods=['GET','POST'])
 def oauth_callback(provider):
        if not current_user.is_anonymous:
            return redirect(url_for('timeline'))
```

Callback to Provider:

```
@app.route('/callback/<provider>',methods=['GET','POST'])
def oauth_callback(provider):
    if not current_user.is_anonymous:
        ###print('Error - The current user is not anonymous','danger') 
        return redirect(url_for('timeline'))

    ###print('Start Callback sign in to Provider','info')  

    try: 
        oauth = OAuthSignIn.get_provider(provider) # problem arrise 
        social_id1, username1, email1, first_name1, last_name1, name1, gender1, profile_url1= oauth.callback()
    except ValueError:
        return render_template('index.html',error="callback failure")
    except OAuthCallbackError as e:
        return render_template('index.html',error=e.errors['error_code'] +" " +e.errors['error']+" : " +e.errors['error_description'])

    if email1 is None:
        email1 = ""


        if db.getUserbySocialID(social_id1).get("id") is None: # if never login by this social account
            db.regisUserSocial(social_id1, email1, datetime_now())

        user = User(social_id = social_id1)

        ImageDirectory = app.config['USER_IMAGE_DIRECTORY']
        SocialIDString = str(social_id1)
        CheckString = SocialIDString[0:6]

        ImageFilename = str(username1) + '.jpg'
        ImageFullDirectoryGlobal = ImageFilename
        ImageURL = str(profile_url1)
        r = requests.get(ImageURL) 
        if CheckString == 'facebo':
            dirname = "FaceBook"
        elif CheckString == 'google':
            dirname = "Google"
        SocialDirectory = dirname + SocialIDString[9:]
        ImageSocialDirectoryGlobal = SocialDirectory
        UserImageDirectory = ImageDirectory+SocialDirectory
        UserImageDirectory = UserImageDirectory + '/'
        ImageFullDirectoryGlobal = UserImageDirectory 
        if not os.path.exists(UserImageDirectory):
            os.makedirs(UserImageDirectory)  
        ImageFullFilename = UserImageDirectory + ImageFilename
        ImageFullFilenameGlobal = ImageFullFilename

        with open(ImageFullFilename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(r.content) 
        ParsingImageDirectory = '../'+ImageDirectory 
        ParsingImageFile = ParsingImageDirectory + 
ImageSocialDirectoryGlobal
        ParsingImageFile = ParsingImageFile + '/'
        ParsingImageFile = ParsingImageFile + ImageFilename

        # TODO remove session
        login_user(user)
        current_user.logintype = "social"
        current_user.confirmed = True

        session['imglocation'] = ParsingImageFile +"?"+ 
        str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d%m%y%H%M%S%f'))
        session['username'] = username1
        session['nickname'] = name1
        session['logged_in'] = True
        session['logged_by'] = 'social'
        session['confirmed'] = True
        session['email'] = current_user.email
        return redirect(url_for('timeline'))
```

If you can find the solution for this OAuthException 191, please help me:

Comment: `https` != `http`

Comment: Yes, I do know that but I still wonder why I got urI as http despite of the fact that I have defined as https